# Can not connect to remote MS Windows machine from local MS Windows machine

Tags: remote

Windows 10 (64 bit), Emacs 25.1

I want to connect from my local Windows machine to remote Windows machine. 
But **Tramp** does not support connecting a remote MS Windows host from a local MS Windows host.

So how I can do this?

Answer (score 1):

Have you installed cygwin on the remote machine? Windows doesn't have a native ssh server (although Windows 10 has recently introduced a beta).

If not, you may want to look at the instructions for installing cygwin and running a ssh server on the remote machine.